# Trigger hourly build from scripted Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cron-task

Is there a way to trigger a Jenkins job to run every hour using the Jenkinsfile *scripted pipeline* syntax?

I have seen examples using the declarative syntax, but none using the pipeline syntax.

**Declarative Syntax Example**

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    triggers {
        cron '@daily'
    }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Build Pipeline Scheduled Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028761/jenkins-build-pipeline-scheduled-trigger)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You could use this snippet for `Scripted pipeline syntax`:

```
properties(
    [
        ...  , // other properties that you have
        pipelineTriggers([cron('0 * * * *')]),
    ]
)
```

Reference for [properties is here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-multibranch/#-properties-%20set%20job%20properties). You can search for "pipelineTriggers" string and find out that triggers for build can be for example artifactory or something else from this list (extracted 2019-03-23 from linked doc page):

```
$class: 'ArtifactoryTrigger'
$class: 'AssemblaBuildTrigger'
bitBucketTrigger
bitbucketPush
$class: 'BuildResultTrigger'
$class: 'CIBuildTrigger'
$class: 'CodingPushTrigger'
$class: 'CronFolderTrigger'
$class: 'DeployDbTrigger'
$class: 'DockerHubTrigger'
$class: 'DosTrigger'
$class: 'ElOyente'
$class: 'FanInReverseBuildTrigger'
$class: 'FeatureBranchAwareTrigger'
$class: 'FilesFoundTrigger'
$class: 'FogbugzStatePoller'
$class: 'FolderContentTrigger'
GenericTrigger
gerrit
$class: 'GhprbTrigger'
$class: 'GitBucketPushTrigger'
githubBranches
githubPullRequests
githubPush
gitee
$class: 'GogsTrigger'
issueCommentTrigger
$class: 'IvyTrigger'
$class: 'JiraChangelogTrigger'
$class: 'JiraCommentTrigger'
$class: 'KanboardQueryTrigger'
$class: 'MailCommandTrigger'
$class: 'MavenDependencyUpdateTrigger'
$class: 'NugetTrigger'
p4Trigger
$class: 'PeriodicFolderTrigger'
$class: 'PollMailboxTrigger'
$class: 'PullRequestBuildTrigger'
$class: 'QuayIoTrigger'
$class: 'RemoteBuildTrigger'
upstream
$class: 'RundeckTrigger'
<code>scm</code>
$class: 'SelfieTrigger'
$class: 'SpoonTrigger'
$class: 'SqsBuildTrigger'
$class: 'TeamPRPushTrigger'
$class: 'TeamPushTrigger'
cron
$class: 'URLTrigger'
snapshotDependencies
$class: 'io.relution.jenkins.awssqs.SQSTrigger'
$class: 'io.relution.jenkins.scmsqs.SQSTrigger'
$class: 'org.cloudbees.literate.jenkins.promotions.PromotionTrigger'
$class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.deploy.weblogic.trigger.DeploymentTrigger'
$class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.deployment.DeploymentTrigger'
```

More info about scripted way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39172513/11152683) (sample from another question).
Documentation that covers declarative pipeline is [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers).

Comment: It does not work in scripted pipelines under jenkins 2.79 (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Undefined symbol ‘pipelineTriggers’)

Comment: For anyone in the future that had the same issue that I had, where its failing syntax-wise, I needed some statement after the `@Library` in my Jenkinsfile. Since I was using the idea from @Clément MATHIEU of `string cron_string = BRANCH_NAME == "master" ? "@hourly" : ""` it works for me.

Answer (score -18):

The correct version is in a Jenkinsfile "Declarative Pipeline":

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
        cron('H */4 * * 1-5')
    }
...
}
```

Comment: The question is specifically about scripted pipeline, not the declarative one.