# Build Periodically Syntax for Jenkins Configuration as Code Plug-In (JCasC)

Tags: jenkins, yaml, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jcasc

I'm trying to use the configuration as code (JCasC) plug-in to create a pipeline job that builds periodically, but I can't find the syntax for this anywhere online. I'm writing the configuration in YAML.

The "Build Periodically" field is under Build Triggers in the pipeline jobs and has a text field called Schedule. My schedule is `0 6-19 * * *`

Is this even possible to do?

This is the yaml file that I am trying to edit:

```
jobs:
  - script: >
      folder('test1'){
        pipelineJob('test1/seedJobTest') {
          description 'seedJobTest'
          logRotator {
            daysToKeep 10
          }
          definition {
            cpsScm {
              scm {
                git {
                  remote {
                    credentials "xxx"
                    url 'xxx'
                  }
                  branches 'refs/head/master'
                  scriptPath 'Jenkinsfile'
                  extensions { }
                }
              }
            }
          }
          configure { project ->
            project / 'properties' / 'EnvInjectJobProperty' {
              'on'('true')
              'info' {
                'propertiesContent'('BRANCH=master')
              }
            }
            project / 'properties' / 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.DisableConcurrentBuildsJobProperty' {}
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a screenshot of where you are putting this syntax? This is definitely possible -- if you hit the (?) and are configuring from the GUI it should give you more hints on the syntax.

Comment: Hi @MarkHan I added a code block to the original question. I did look under the (?) in the GUI but it looked like it was more for cron syntax rather than for CASC. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh I see, good call. I think I may have found what you're looking for. Check my answer. @Katie

Comment: @MarkHan I tried that, but it sets the "Poll SCM" trigger rather than the "Build Periodically" one.

Comment: Can you try `triggers { cron('0 6-19 * * *) }` ? @Katie

Comment: Also, it's possible that you may want to reserve CASC plugin for configuring Jenkins, and then for configuration of Jobs to use scripted / declarative pipelines within your Jenkinsfile. If you do, then see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44113834/trigger-hourly-build-from-scripted-jenkinsfile for Scripted Pipeline, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168861/build-periodically-with-a-multi-branch-pipeline-in-jenkins for Declarative Pipeline. In your case, it may be beneficial if you posted the contents of the referenced Jenkinsfile. We may be able to achieve chron job within that.

Comment: I used 'triggers { cron('0 6-19 * * *) }' and that worked! Thank you!! @MarkHan and thanks, I'll look in configuring the jobs within my Jenkinsfile

Comment: Awesome! That's great to here. I edited my answer to make sure future viewers can also digest this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using JCasC to configure your build/pipeline configuration:

To build periodically, **regardless of SCM changes**, you can add this block:

```
triggers { 
    cron('0 6-19 * * *')
}
```

To build periodically, **only if** there were SCM changes, you can use this block:

```
triggers {
    scm('0 6-19 * * *')
}
```

To view this answer in context, *here is a code snippet example*:

```
jobs:
  - script: |
    job('PROJ-unit-tests') {
        scm {
            git(gitUrl)
        }
        triggers { 
            cron('0 6-19 * * *')
        }
        steps {
            maven('-e clean test')
        }
    }
```

Snippet taken and adjusted from: https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/issues/876